# Does Google TCP Load Balancer replicate traffic between all target groups?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

I've configured a TCP Load Balancer in Google Cloud and I can see the option to select more than one single instance group to send traffic.

[image]

What does really Google Cloud does when selecting more than two instance group? It balances the traffic using the sum of all instances on both instance groups? or it balances the load on the first instance group and then balances the load on the second instance group?

I'm more interested in the second aproach, so I would like to know how to get this in Google Cloud.

Comment: Instance groups are a mechanism for autoscaling. The LoadBalancer see's and performs loadbalancing between the nodes equally regardless of which Instance groups they belong to.

Answer (score 1):

Load balancer handles traffic depending on the load balancing algorithm we configured at backend and by default it uses Round Robin Algorithm.

**Load balancer performs the following functions:**

1. Distributes client requests or network load efficiently across
   multiple servers.
2. Ensures high availability and reliability by sending requests only
   to servers that are online
3. Provides the flexibility to add or subtract servers as demand
   dictates

Different load balancing algorithms provide different benefits; the choice of [load balancing method](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/internal) depends on your needs:

**Round Robin** – Requests are distributed across the group of servers sequentially.

**Least Connections** – A new request is sent to the server with the fewest current connections to clients. The relative computing capacity of each server is factored into determining which one has the least connections.

**Least Time** – Sends requests to the server selected by a formula that combines the
fastest response time and fewest active connections. Exclusive to NGINX Plus.

**Hash** – Distributes requests based on a key you define, such as the client IP address or
the request URL. NGINX Plus can optionally apply a consistent hash to minimize redistribution
of loads if the set of upstream servers changes.

**IP Hash** – The IP address of the client is used to determine which server receives the request.

**Random with Two Choices** – Picks two servers at random and sends the request to the
one that is selected by then applying the Least Connections algorithm (or for NGINX Plus
the Least Time algorithm, if so configured).

For more information, see [setting of LB](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/internal/setting-up-internal#configure_instances_and_instance_groups) and [Adding an instance group to a load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/adding-an-instance-group-to-a-load-balancer)

Comment: @fernandezr : Adding for above , while creating back end configurations we can see option called "traffic policy" in GCP Console, in this policy we need to choose any one algorithm listed as above depends on the need of  traffic.